# The sign of the complementary minor of a Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on this problem which looks rather basic : Let $A$ be any matrix .Prove that the sign of a minor $A[I,J]$ and its complementary minor $A[I',J']$ are the same...... Basically I am looking at the definitions and some examples with actual Matrices to see a pattern but have not made any progress yet....

Comment: I'm not certain if this is always true, but I think you might need to impose some conditions on $A$ for it to hold.

Comment: It seems that this is already wrong for $2\times2$ matrices, where a minor and its complementary minor are simply elements of the matrix, which can have arbitrary signs.

Comment: This isn't even true when $A$ is positive definite symmetric.